# error: attribute 'com.xyz.abc:itemBackground' not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use android bottom navigation drawer and i'm facing some issues. [image]

Here is the Gradle file of my project :

[image]

I had some conflicts when i used v28 library along with dexter and probably with retrofit hence i have added these lines:

```
*implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'*
```

and *{
                exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
                exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            }*

part.

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/accent_white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_text"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error stated : Attribute itemBackground,itemIconTint,itemTextColor,menu are not found. Please help me with this issue.

one example : **error: attribute 'com.app.abc.xyz:itemBackground' not found**.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to share your layout and error as **`TEXT`** not as **`IMAGE`**

Comment: I hope last line of the question states that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` already indicates you need to add the support design library to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:XX.X.X'

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was dealing with other gradle issues accidentally i had removed that line.